# Retrieve image from url using dlib

Tags: python, image, dlib

I want to retrieve an image from the url using the dlib library.

I have tried the following code:

```
win = dlib.image_window()
img = dlib.load_rgb_image(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
win.set_image(img)
```

But the window opens empty, when I expected the image from the url to open.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, this seems to display the image for me:

```
import urllib.request
import dlib
import numpy
import io
from PIL import Image

win = dlib.image_window()

img = numpy.array(Image.open(io.BytesIO(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())))

win.set_image(img)
```